# Wie schreibt man "der/die/das"(kursiv bzw. großgeschrieben) in handschriftlichen Texten?

Tags: handwriting, typography

*Der korrekte Begriff für dieses Phänomen ist mir leider nicht geläufig, deswegen würde ich mich auf eine Korrektur der Frage freuen.*

> Wolfsburg ist *die*/DIE Autostadt.
>
> Freilich *den* Geruch der Menschen gab es nicht, genauso wenig wie es *das* menschliche Antlitz gab./aus "Das Parfum"/
>
> Es gibt nicht *die* Jugendsprache, sondern eine Vielzahl an Varietäten.

Also damit hebt man bestimmte Wörter hervor, um ihre Einzigartigkeit zu zeigen. Wie schreibt man so etwas in handschriftlichen Texten?

Comment: Man unterstreicht.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Derartige Akzentuierungen bringt man heute handschriftlich in der Regel mittels Unterstreichung zum Ausdruck.

Siehe auch: http://hypermedia.ids-mannheim.de/call/public/sysgram.ansicht?v_typ=d&v_id=2355

Wenn man sich mit älteren Schriften beschäftigt, kann man übrigens schön sehen, dass es früher viel mehr Möglichkeiten zur Hervorhebung gegeben hat. Im 19. Jahrhundert wurden Worthervorhebungen zum Beispiel oft dadurch kenntlich gemacht, dass man einzelne Wörter in humanistischer Kursive oder "lateinischer" Schrift geschrieben hat, während der Rest des Textes in Kurrentschrift geschrieben wurde. So konnte man sogar noch unterschiedliche Hervorhebungen voneinander unterscheiden. In dieser Hinsicht sind wir heute etwas beschränkt ...

Comment: Das bringt auch irre viel, wenn man 3, 4 Hervorhebungsformen hat. Kursiv, fett,   g e s p e r r t   schreiben, unterstrichen - in Kombination sind das schon 24 Möglichkeiten.

Comment: Kann von euch irgendjemand handschriftlich *kursiv* schreiben, so dass man einen Unterschied sieht? Ihr müsst echte Handschriftengenies sein...

Comment: Sehr schöne Antwort. Hätten Sie ein paar Links oder Bilder?

Comment: Hier zum Beispiel, hoffe der Link geht: http://www.gda.bayern.de/DigitaleSchriftkunde/1856_BayHStA_MInn_41166_01.html - Der Schreiber schreibt den Haupttext in Kurrent; lateinische Wörter, die Anrede an den König und Nachnamen sind in humanistischer Kursive geschrieben. Zusätzlich gibt es auch noch Unterstreichungen zur Akzentuierung (z.B. "nicht" in Z. 25).

Answer (score 6):

Es kommt darauf an, was die Schreiberin gerade tun möchte. Gesehen habe ich bisher:

- Versalien oder Kapitälchen
- unterstreichen
- umkasteln, also ein Kästchen darumzeichnen, oder umkreisen
- anderen Stift beziehungsweise andere Stiftfarbe nehmen
- wenn alles andere verbunden geschrieben wird, das hervorzuhebende Wort in Blockbuchstaben schreiben
- drei- oder viermal nachziehen, um einen fetteren Strich zu erhalten
- und wahrscheinlich noch ein paar mehr, die mir gerade nicht mehr einfallen.

Es klingt abgedroschen, aber der Kreativität sind keine Grenzen gesetzt.

Comment: Ich schreibe in handschriftlichen Notizen (Personen-)Namen meist in Kapitälchen und ich würde einzelne Wörter eher einkreisen (mit krakeliger Ellipse) als ein Rechteck zu zeichnen. Nicht zu vergessen: Anführungszeichen, auch wenn ich selbst die nie so verwenden würde.